# ValueError at / Field 'id' expected a number but got 'srednje'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have django application. I want user to type url with name of certain article in browser and then they will see all products linked to this article. My models look like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    a_article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

And I try to get this work in my view:

```
def product(request, pk):
    product = models.Product.objects.filter(a_article=pk)
    return render(request, 'product.html')
```

Since I passed `pk` in my function I put it in urls as well:

```
path('<str:pk>/', views.product, name='product'),
```

When I run this and get on url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/srednje/` I get an error:

```
ValueError at /srednje/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'srednje'.
```

I think this is probably somehow linked to primary key or foreign key but how and how can I change this to work?

Comment: As you can see error what error says *`Field 'id' expected a number but got 'srednje'.`* means you've passed `/srednje/` inside your url instead of `id` eg. *1,2,3*

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you must change `product` line to:

```
product = models.Product.objects.filter(a_article__slug=pk)
```

if you want to fetch products based on article primary keys, then you should use

```
product = models.Product.objects.filter(a_article__pk=pk)
```

It is suggested to use names according to the name of field you are referring.
So, if you want to fetch by article slug, it is recommended to use:

`views.py`

```
def product(request, slug):
    product = models.Product.objects.filter(a_article__slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'product.html')
```

`urls.py`

```
path('<str:slug>/', views.product, name='product'),
```

Comment: It works, I don't get an error anymore, but I don't get products either. When I print(product) I get <QuerySet []>. I want to get all products that have same foreign key that is my slug.

Comment: Add multiple products with same slug and try.